# Is it possible to call properties in constructor in C# so I don't have to write the validating check of the value twice?

Tags: c#, properties, constructor

I am studying Java and recently I started studying C# as well. In Java I was told to write the set method of some member of the class with a check to validate, for example if it is a String - the string not to be null. Then we call the set method in the constructor and when I initialize an object of the class using constructor it validates my data.

So in C# there are the so called properties which should be the same logic as set/get methods in Java and I can validate my data in the property.

How can I call that set method/set property in the constructor in C# so I don't have to write the validating code twice - once in the property and once in the constructor?

Code: Some simple example of class

```
class Program
{
    private int someVariable;

    public Program(int someVariable)
    {
        this.someVariable = someVariable;
    }

    public int SomeVariable
    {
        get { return someVariable; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }
            else
            {
                someVariable = value;
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program pr = new Program(10);
        pr.SomeVariable = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification :) as for the C# and Java , i have been told(not my own opinion, I am not that much into the programming) that Java as platform is good almost as .net but the languages C# just fix the mistakes in Java like the set/get methods and generics,events etc.

Answer (score 6):

You would call `this.SomeVariable` in your constructor which would then execute the `set` part of your property and validate the value. Right now, you are bypassing this by directly setting the variable `someVariable` value (at times called the 'backing field')

Usually in C#, I keep the backing field and the property next to each other so that it is easier to read the code, like this:

```
int _someVariable;
public int SomeVariable
{
    get { return _someVariable; }
    set { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just access the property from your constructor:

```
public Program(int someVariable)
{
    SomeVariable = someVariable;
}
```

Note: You should probably not write directly to the console in your setter. A better way to do it would be to throw an exception -- that way the rest of your program can do something about it. Alternatively, you could just set a default value if the value passed in is out of range.

```
public int SomeVariable
{
    get { return someVariable; }
    set
    {
        if(value > 5)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("SomeVariable cannot be greater than 5.");
        someVariable = value;
    }
}
```

Or,

```
public int SomeVariable
{
    get { return someVariable; }
    set
    {
        someVariable = value > 5 ? 5 : value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just do it.

```
public Program(int someVariable)
{
    SomeVariable = someVariable;
}
```